# Mean of fields in a structure using structfun, Matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, data-structures, mean

I have a structure in the following format:

```
A.L1.data = <1000x3 double>
A.L2.data = <1000x3 double>
A.L3.data = <1000x3 double>
```

I would like to obtain the mean of the first column of all the fields, i.e. one vector of 1000 rows that is the mean of L1, L2 and L3.

I have tried using structfun with the following code:

```
foo = structfun(@(x) mean(x.data(:,1)), A, 'UniformOutput', false)
```

However, this gives me the mean (single value) of each first column rather than the mean of all the fields.

If I do:

```
 foo = structfun(@(x) mean(x.data), A, 'UniformOutput', false)
```

I obtain the mean of each column for each field.

How should I modify my code?

Comment: `x.data(:,1)` is used to signify the first column, basic MATLAB index syntax. Try `mean(x.data)` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access all data of a struct by `struct2array`.

Get struct `firstColumnsOfData` with fields `L1` `L2` `L3` with the first columns of `data`:

```
firstColumnsOfData = structfun(@(x) x.data(:,1), A, 'UniformOutput', false)
```

Get mean of each element of `L1` `L2` `L3`:

```
mL123 =  mean(struct2array(firstColumnsOfData')) % transpose to not get mean of each field
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand your question to mean that you want the mean of `A.L1.data(ii,1)`, `A.L2.data(ii,1)`, and `A.L3.data(ii,1)`, thereby creating a column vector with 1000 entries. With `structfun`, I don't see how you can apply it across fields in the structure as this applies the function provided to every field in the structure sequentially.

I think what you want is this:

```
bar = mean([A.L1.data(:,1) A.L2.data(:,1) A.L3.data(:,1)], 2);
```

Passing `2` as the second argument to mean provides the mean across the rows as opposed to down the columns.

Comment: I don't have enough points to comment on @JaBe's solution, but should note that `struct2array` does not exist in R2015b. Also, in earlier version of Matlab, it'd be better to use the second argument to mean than to transpose the dataset. The following works: `mean(cell2mat(struct2cell(firstColumnsOfData)'), 2);`

Comment: I am running Matlab R2015b on OSX, and `struct2array` does exist.

Comment: Ah, it's in the Signal Processing toolbox. My solution does not require a toolbox.